# Splitting Eloquent methods between model and controller?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this code in a Controller:

```
public function getStock(Request $request){

    $laptops = new Laptop;
    $laptops->addJoins();
    $laptops->filterResults($request);
    return $laptops->get();
}
```

In the laptops Model I have:

```
public function addJoins() {
    $this->Join('locations', 'locations.id', '=', 'laptops.location_id');
    $this->Join('models', 'models.id', '=', 'laptops.model_id');
    $this->Join('types', 'types.id', '=', 'models.type');
    $this->leftJoin('statuses', 'status.id', '=', 'laptops.status');
    $this->leftJoin('earmarks', 'earmarks.laptop', '=', 'laptop.id');
}

public function filterResults($request) {
    if ($request->stock) {
        $this->where('locations.stock', 0);
    }

    if ($request->loc) {
        $this->where('laptops.location_id', $request->loc);
    }
}
```

The problem is I receive all laptop records, and the filtering from URL parameters doesn't appear to be working at all. Am I barking up the wrong tree with this structure (I'm very new to Laravel)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filtering isn't working because running your queries on `$this` will result in unwanted behavior, this is what local scopes are for. See the documentation for them here:

https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#local-scopes

In your case it would be:

Your Laptop model:

```
public function scopeAddJoins($query)
{
    return $query->join('locations', 'locations.id', '=', 'laptops.location_id')
        ->join('models', 'models.id', '=', 'laptops.model_id')
        ->join('types', 'types.id', '=', 'models.type')
        ->leftJoin('statuses', 'status.id', '=', 'laptops.status')
        ->leftJoin('earmarks', 'earmarks.laptop', '=', 'laptop.id');
}

public function scopeFilterResults($query, $request)
{
    if ($request->has('stock')) {
        $query->where('locations.stock', 0);
    }

    if ($request->has('loc')) {
        $query->where('laptops.location_id', $request->input('loc'));
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Then you can do this in your Controller:

```
public function getStock(Request $request)
{
    return Laptop::addJoins()->filterResults($request)->get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works (well, it moaned about trying to call addJoins as a non-static method, so I made both methods static. Does that matter?). So, does Laravel automatically know what $query is whenever it's passed into a function? Thanks again

Comment: One more question, the records being returned have some surprising NULL values (like id!). Any idea why? `{"id":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"asset_tag":454,"serial":null,"hostname":null,"model_id":1,"os":null,"encrypted":null,"location_id":1,"detected_location_id":null,"user":null,"detected_user":null,"recent_users":null,"purchased":null,"purchased_from":null,"warranty_expires":null,"scrapped":null,"scrapped_on":null,"scrapped_by":null,"notes":null,"status":null,"location":null,"stock":1,"address":null,"org_unit_path":null,"google_location":null,"public_ips":nul'`

Comment: Yes the static function matter, don't use them.  As for the non-static method error, I'm guessing that's because you named the method in your model `addJoins`?  For Model query methods you need to prefix the method name with `scope`.  On your model the method names should be `scopeAddJoins` and `scopeFilterResults` which are callable from your controller statically as `Laptop::addJoins()->filterResults($request)->get();`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Lastly, how do I chain a 'has' statement onto this? For instance, where the Laptop 'has' entries in the earmark table, or doesn't have entries in the table?

Comment: Laravel will automatically inject `$query` as the first parameter when calling a scope{$methodName} on a model.  When you call a method on a model that doesn't exist on that model it creates a new instance of Eloquent Builder so `$builder = Laptop::addJoins()` returns the builder then every call after that is on that builder instance.  Calling it again on `Laptop` will create a new builder instance which is why it wasn't working correctly for you before.  When you call a method on the builder it checks if you have a scope method defined on that model and calls it while injecting the query.

Comment: As for your null id columns it's because one of your joins has a table with null id's.  To return the data you want from the tables you want select the columns per table as in: `Laptop::select('laptops.*', 'models.name', 'types.name')` you can even alias the selects inline (which is needed if you have columns with the same name across joined tables) like: `Laptop::select('laptops.*', 'models.name as model_name', 'types.name as type_name')->addJoins()->filterResults($request)->get()`

Comment: For the `has()` statement you can do it one of two ways since it is referencing a joined table.  First would be to change your `leftJoin` to a `join` or if you have an `earmarks()` relation defined on your `Laptop` model then you can do `Laptop::has('earmarks')->addJoins()->filterResults($request)->get()`

Comment: Thanks, that works great. So I did this. It's starting to bulk up my Controller, but I can't think of anywhere else to put it `if ($request->has('em') && $request->em === '1') {
            $laptops = Laptop::has('earmark')->addJoins()->filterResults($request);
        } elseif ($request->has('em') && $request->em === '0') {
            $laptops = Laptop::has('earmark', '<', 1)->addJoins()->filterResults($request);
        } else {
            $laptops = Laptop::addJoins()->filterResults($request);
        }`

Comment: For that use the `when()` method like `Laptop::when($request->has('earmark'), function($query) { return $query->has('earmark'); }, function($query) { return $query->doesntHave('earmark'); })` but this wouldn't give you the option to not filter based on `earmark`.  I ran in to a larger problem similar to this and wrote a package to solve it.  It may be what you're looking for if the above isn't what you're looking for. https://github.com/Tucker-Eric/EloquentFilter

Comment: That looks really neat, I think I will use it. Thanks again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127377/discussion-between-daninthemix-and-eric-tucker).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reinventing the wheel I'd recommend you to change structure. Skinny controller, fat model. The good practice is to keep controllers as thin as possible, so my controller would look like this:

```
public function getStock(Request $request)
{
    return view('laptop.index', [
       'laptops' => Laptop::getAllLaptops($request->all())
    ]);
}
```

Also, use Eloquent and [scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#query-scopes) for filtering etc. All data related logic would be in model:

```
public function getAllLaptops($data)
{
    return $this->with('locations', 'models', 'types', 'statuses', 'earmarks')->search($data)->get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question was about why my methods don't appear to be working - the 'where' clauses aren't executing if I pass in the relevant URL parameters. I just get all records returned in any case. Wondered if I'm missing something simple and obvious.

Comment: @daninthemix, you're reinventing the wheel here, that's why you don't see any answers here. Laravel developers just don't code like this. Even if you'll make your code work, your app will be unmaintainable. I've tried to show you the right way. Laravel has all tools to accomplish your task, so learn how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that `$request->stock` and `$request->loc` does not have any value in your URL parameters. If you are calling the route this way:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/yourpath?stock&loc
```

Instead, try to use it this way:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/yourpath?stock=1&loc=1
```

The point is to give them some value.

Comment: It's not that, they do have values.